# Firestore asks me create the index that is already exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to paginate comments. The first 10 comments is loading ok, but next ones (when query contains `startAfterDocument`) return error like:

```
Query(comments where movie_id == 1041047 order by -created, __name__) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/.......
```

But this index is already exist, I created it before. And if I follow the suggestion link Firebase Console tells me the same: this index is exist.

```dart
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> _loadPageFrom(
      int index, DocumentSnapshot lastDoc) async {
    Query query = Firestore.instance
        .collection('comments')
        .where('movie_id', isEqualTo: movieID)
        .orderBy('created', descending: true);

    if (lastDoc != null) query = query.startAfterDocument(lastDoc);
    final snapshot = await query.limit(10).getDocuments();

    return snapshot.documents;
  }
```

What problem is here?

Comment: Had this same problem.  Just waited a little while and it worked... new queries need to propagate and it takes a little time...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you had recently deleted your index, you will need to wait a little bit until it's deleted from your project inside GCP, after that you will be able to create it again.

Comment: Worked for me after waiting 15 minutes,

Comment: Worked for me after waiting several hours.